# Is Java SE embedded discontinued in Java 10?

Tags: java, java-8

I want to know whether java Se embedded will not be available from Java 10. The latest version is JDK8u181

Comment: What makes you think that?

Comment: It is mentioned in the Java SE embedded download page

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because that's a question for Oracle customer support, not stack overflow. It's also not specific to programming.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is replaced by the Compact Profile support via JEP 161

http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/161

In short, you can now generate a JRE which has only the support you need for your application, possibly adding things not in the Embedded version, but removing anything you don't use to make the JRE as compact as possible.

> Summary
>
> Define a few subset Profiles of the Java SE Platform Specification so that applications that do not require the entire Platform can be deployed and run on small devices.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/resources/tech/compact-profiles-overview-2157132.html

> Java SE Embedded 8 introduces a new concept called, Compact Profiles, which enable reduced memory footprint for applications that do not require the entire Java platform. The Java SE 8 javac compiler has a new -profile option, which allows the application to be compiled using one of the new supported profiles.
>
> There are three supported profiles: compact1, compact2 and compact3. These are additive layers, so that each Profile contains all of the APIs in the previous smaller Compact Profiles and adds appropriate APIs on top. The compact profiles feature is useful in small devices. It also can be used to shorten the time to download an application from a download server, such as an "App Store."  It makes for more compact deployment of Java applications that bundle the JRE. A JRE can be configured with a compact profile, reducing its footprint for deployment along with a compact profile application.
>
> Overview
>
> A compact profile is a subset of the full Java SE Platform API. Because they have a smaller storage footprint, compact profiles can enable many Java applications to run on resource-constrained devices. Choosing a compact profile that closely matches an application's functional needs minimizes the storage devoted to unused functions.  There are new embedded developer tools in Java SE Embedded 8 including jrecreate and jdeps, which allow a developer to customize the Compact Profile runtime environment for a platform, and to find the Compact Profile dependencies for analysis during platform development.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Oracle's page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/downloads/index.html):

> JDK 8 is the final major Oracle Java SE Embedded Product
>
> Oracle Java SE 8 Embedded is the final major release of the Oracle Java SE Embedded product. Starting with JDK 9, Oracle doesn't plan to offer a separate Java SE Embedded product download. Java SE 8 Embedded is now on restricted availability intended for existing embedded support customers only. For more information, please consult the Java SE PM blog